# How to delete from table with join

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inner-join, sql-delete

I am trying to delete from the PAINTING table while joining with the MUSEUM table. The query I am running is giving me an error saying "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended". For reference I have pasted my query below.

```
DELETE FROM PAINTING
    INNER JOIN MUSEUM ON PAINTING.Museum_Name = MUSEUM.MuseumName
    WHERE MUSEUM.MuCountry = 'France' OR MUSEUM.MuCountry = 'Spain';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you would use a correlated subquery.

```
delete from painting p
where exists (
    select 1 from museum m where pm.museum_name = m.museum_name and m.mu_country = 'France'
)
```

Comment: Okay, that works for deleting all Paintings from France. If I also wanted to delete painting from Spain can I add "OR m.MuCountry = 'Spain'" to the end?

Comment: @hasse:  `and (and m.mu_country = 'France' or and m.mu_country = 'Spain')` - the parentheses are important here. But `in` is better: `and m.mu_country in ('France', 'Spain')`. Or: